# To derive Posteriors from Conjugate Priors, do we just multiply the terms in the PDFs with the parameters of interest?

Tags: bayesian, prior, conjugate-prior

Consider the beta-binomial model (beta prior, binomial likelihood). So we have$$
\begin{align}
P(\theta)&\sim \text{Beta}(\theta|\hat a,\hat b)
\propto \theta^{\hat a-1}(1-\theta)^{\hat b-1}\\
P(Y|\theta) &\propto \theta^{N_1}(1-\theta)^{N_0}
\end{align}
$$
where $N_1, N_0$ are the usual empirical counts for the likelihood.

The derivation in my book seems to have no interest in working out the posterior with the normalizing constants as in:$$
P(\theta|Y)\propto P(\theta)P(Y|\theta)\propto \text{Beta}(\theta|\hat \alpha+N_1,\alpha+N_0)
$$
Notice that any multiplicative constants not related to $\theta$ is disregarded in the derivation.

My question is, if the prior is fully conjugate to the likelihood, can we ignore the normalizing constants for each distribution and multiply them to get another distribution without normalizing constants.

I will then match the resulting product with whatever distribution similar to it. In the case above, the product is proportional to a beta distribution (ignoring the constants).

Comment: Whether or not the prior is conjugate one can safely ignore all multiplicative constants in the prior density and the likelihood function, since the product need be normalised by its integral to be a probability density.

Comment: Ok thank you I understand now. When I try to solve for $\int P(X,\theta)/Z=1$ I find myself comparing the Beta distribution for the terms inside the integral.